# Formik Error Passing To Submit Not Working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux-toolkit, formik

Hi guys i want to pass 'error' coming from nodejs backend to onsubmit the problem that even if the error passes i still navigate to login page
this is my code :

```
import "./form_inscription.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { validationSchemaBase } from "./formsScema";
//reactstrap componenets
import { FormGroup, Label, Input, Alert } from "reactstrap";
//icons and assets
import ArrowLeft from "../../../../assets/icons/Arrow-Left.png";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
// import { registerUser } from "../../../../store/features/authentication/inscription/inscriptionThunk";
import { registerUser } from "../../../../store/features/authentication/authentificationThunk";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Eye, EyeOff } from "react-feather";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const FormIscriptionEtape1 = () => {
  const [checkboxError, setCheckboxError] = useState(false);
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const { error } = useSelector((store) => store.authentification);

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    if (values.password === values.passConfirm) {
      //checkbox error handling conditions
      if (values.cPartner || values.aPartner || values.sPartner) {
        setCheckboxError(false);
        dispatch(registerUser(values));
        if (!error) {
          navigate("/login");
        }
      } else {
        setCheckboxError(true);
      }
      //catch error handling
    } else {
      console.log("mot de passe non conforme!!");
    }
  };

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setShowPassword((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  //formik data management
  const {
    values,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
    setFieldValue,
    errors,
    touched,
  } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      passConfirm: "",
      cPartner: false,
      aPartner: false,
      sPartner: false,
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchemaBase.test(
      "one check-box-required",
      "Veuillez sélectionner le type de votre organsime",
      (values) => values.aPartner || values.sPartner || values.cPartner
    ),
    onSubmit,
  });

  //handle check boxes
  const handleChangeBox = (event) => {
    const { name, value, checked } = event.target;

    if (name === "cPartner" || name === "aPartner" || name === "sPartner") {
      setFieldValue(name, checked);

      if (name === "cPartner") {
        setFieldValue("aPartner", false);
        setFieldValue("sPartner", false);
        setCheckboxError(false);
      } else if (name === "aPartner") {
        setFieldValue("cPartner", false);
        setFieldValue("sPartner", false);
        setCheckboxError(false);
      } else {
        setFieldValue("cPartner", false);
        setFieldValue("aPartner", false);
        setCheckboxError(false);
      }
    } else {
      setFieldValue(name, value);
      setCheckboxError(false);
    }
  };

  //navigation to Login screen through the back button temporary will be deleted in the future
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleNavigateLogin = () => {
    navigate("/login");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="w-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div className="w-50 mb-1">
          <FormGroup className="mt-2">
            <Label
              className="label_title_inscription text_600_nrm"
              for="exampleEmail"
            >
              Email
            </Label>
            <Input
              className="input_text_off"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
            {errors.email && (
              <p className="validation_problems">{errors.email}</p>
            )}
          </FormGroup>
        </div>
        <div className="w-50 mb-1">
          <div className=" justify-content-between">
            <FormGroup className="auth-login-form mt-2">
              <Label
                className="label_title_inscription text_600_nrm"
                for="examplePassword"
              >
                Mot de passe
              </Label>
              <Input
                className="input_text_off"
                type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                name="password"
                value={values.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
              />
              {/* <div
                className="password-visibility-icon"
                onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
              >
                {showPassword ? <Eye size={20} /> : <EyeOff size={20} />}
              </div> */}
              {errors.password && touched.password && (
                <p className="validation_problems">{errors.password}</p>
              )}
            </FormGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-50 mb-1">
          <div className=" justify-content-between">
            <FormGroup className="auth-login-form mt-2">
              <Label
                className="label_title_inscription text_600_nrm"
                for="examplePassword"
              >
                Confirmation mot de passe
              </Label>
              <Input
                className="input_text_off"
                type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                name="passConfirm"
                value={values.passConfirm}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
              />
              {/* <div
                className="password-visibility-icon"
                onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
              >
                {showPassword ? <Eye size={20} /> : <EyeOff size={20} />}
              </div> */}
              {errors.passConfirm && touched.passConfirm && (
                <p className="validation_problems">{errors.passConfirm}</p>
              )}
            </FormGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* checkbox section */}
      <p className="text-center mt-5 checkbox_text_inscription text_600_nrm">
        Vous êtes
      </p>
      {checkboxError && (
        <p className="validation_problems error_validation_check">
          Veuillez sélectionner le type de votre organsime
        </p>
      )}
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center checkbox">
        <div className="form-check d-flex checks_gap">
          <Input
            type="checkbox"
            className="form-check"
            name="cPartner"
            checked={values.cPartner}
            onChange={handleChangeBox}
          />
          <Label
            className="form-check-Label checkbox_text_inscription text_600_nrm"
            htmlFor="formrow-customCheck"
          >
            Commercial
          </Label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check d-flex checks_gap">
          <Input
            type="checkbox"
            className="form-check"
            name="sPartner"
            checked={values.sPartner}
            onChange={handleChangeBox}
          />
          <Label
            className="form-check-Label checkbox_text_inscription text_600_nrm"
            htmlFor="formrow-customCheck"
          >
            Educatif
          </Label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check d-flex checks_gap">
          <Input
            type="checkbox"
            className="form-check"
            name="aPartner"
            checked={values.aPartner}
            onChange={handleChangeBox}
          />
          <Label
            className="form-check-Label checkbox_text_inscription text_600_nrm"
            htmlFor="formrow-customCheck"
          >
            Associatif
          </Label>
        </div>
      </div>
      {error ? <Alert color="danger">{error.message}</Alert> : null}{" "}
      <div className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-end mt-5">
        {/* <button
          className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center btn_next_back"
          onClick={handleNavigateLogin}
        >
          <img src={ArrowLeft} alt="" />
        </button> */}
        <button type="submit" className="btn_next_step" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Suivant
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormIscriptionEtape1;
```

i tried passing error to onsubmit props but it gives me undefined everytime so the only way that my error passes is the way i am writing the code right now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of this typo?

```js
(store) => store.authentification
```

it should probably be "authentication"

```js
(store) => store.authentication
```